# Filtering CURRENTGROUP() in DAX to get the last value by date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table on a granularity **month-product category-customer**.

| month | customer | category | sales | sales_year_ago | number_of_stores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | cust1 | category1 | 100 | 90 | 5 |
| 2023-09-01 | cust1 | category1 | 120 | 100 | 3 |
| 2023-08-01 | cust1 | category1 | 150 | 110 | 7 |

My ultimate goal is to sum `sales` column for rows in the table filtered by columns from the table itself or their derivatives, no interaction with other tables.

I achieve this by the following formula.

1. I do double `GROUPBY` as I need to calculate on customer-category level, but at the same time if several months are chosen in slicers, I want to sum them at customer-category level.
2. I use `ADDCOLUMNS` to calculate derivative columns.
3. Then I filter by new columns and sum sales for the filtered table.

```
Measure = 
VAR _tbl1 = 
GROUPBY(
    initial_table,
    initial_table[month],
    initial_table[customer],
    initial_table[category],
    "sales", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), initial_table[sales]),
    "sales_ya", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), initial_table[sales_year_ago]),
    "num_of_stores", MAXX(CURRENTGROUP(), initial_table[number_of_stores])
)

VAR _tbl2 =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    GROUPBY(
        _tbl1,
        [customer],
        [category],
        "SALES", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), [sales]),
        "SALES_YA", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), [sales_ya]),
        "NUM_OF_STORES", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), [num_of_stores])
    ),
    "SALES INDEX YA", DIVIDE([SALES], [SALES_YA]) * 100
)
return

SUMX(
    FILTER(
        _tbl2,
        [SALES INDEX YA] < 100
    ),
    [SALES]
)
```

The problem is that for the column `number_of_stores` I want to get the value for the last month  in `_tbl2`, not the sum or max. It could have been achieved by filtering `CURRENTGROUP()` for the last month, but it can't be filtered.

In short, `NUM_OF_STORES` column in `_tbl2` should be the value for the last month in `CURRENTGROUP`.

So the virtual `_tbl2` for the example table should look like this given that I chose all 3 months  in a slicer.

| customer | category | SALES | SALES_YA | NUM_OF_STORES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust1 | category1 | 370 | 200 | 5 |